# jquery layerslider: stop layerslider when mouseover on navigation bar (nav)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jquery layerslider ,want to stop layerslider when I mouseover my navigation bar (nav).

```
// Java script code
    $('document').ready(function()
               {
                // Calling LayerSlider on your selected element after the document loaded
                $('#layerslider').layerSlider({
                    responsive: true,
                    animateFirstLayer:false,
                   autostart:false,
                    skin      : 'default',
                    skinsPath : '/layerslider/skins/'
                  // showCircleTimer:false

                });
                  $('.onHoverService').mouseover (function(){
                          autoStart : false
                  });
                  $('.onHoverService').mouseout (function(){
                          autoStart : true
                  });
               });
//HTML code
        <nav class="nav-inner">
                  <div class="background_logo"><a href="http://www.blacknova.com.au/">
                 <img class="horizontal_logo" src="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/bnlogohorisontal.png" height="35" >
                 <!--<img class="home_logo" src="<?php  echo $this->webroot; ?>img/home-button-white.png" height="25" >-->
                   </a>    </div>
                      <?php  echo $this->element('Menus/menuHeader');?> 
                   <div class="servicedropdownMenu">

                      <?php echo $this->element('Menus/headerServices');?>  

                  </div>
                  <div class="portfoliodropdownMenu">

                      <?php     echo $this->element('Menus/headerPortfolio');?>  

                  </div>


             </nav>
```

I had tried above code , but its not working properly. I am new to it . Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Add `pauseOnHover: true,`

Example:

```
    $('#layerslider').layerSlider({
        responsive: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        animateFirstLayer:false,
        autostart:false,
        skin      : 'default',
        skinsPath : '/layerslider/skins/'
        // showCircleTimer:false
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Avi is right, you can easily set it to pause when you hover over the slider by adding it to your onpage script. (as of version 1.6)

See http://www.docs.purethemes.net/sukces/layerslider/documentation/documentation.html#global_settings  which states:

"pauseOnHover : true or false
If ture, SlideShow will pause when you move the mouse pointer over the LayerSlider container."

Answer (score 0):

In case of the function `layerSlider()` you're passing object literals `{}` which hold properties or options. Careful now because that's not the same when you call `mouseover()`. In this case the argument you're passing is a `function` which will instantiate itself anonymously (it doesn't have a name) like:

```
function(){
    // do something here
}
```

In your case I believe you want to call jQuery's `stop()` function on the slider.
Something along the lines of:

```
function(){
    $('#layerslider').stop(true, true);
}
```

Comment: I know about juery stop function . but ,in my case the layer slider I am using is kind of plugin.

Comment: it is using "layerslider.kreaturamedia.jquery" js file. and this file having code which I am not getting.u can download and can have a look . I am not able to find animate function in it. its library file.

Comment: Ah right, I have been looking that up but it was `$.fn.animate` and wasn't sure if `stop()` would apply here

Comment: script animate-background-position.js?ver=2.3.0 ln. 27